# How to programatically dock MFC MDI child windows

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I've generated a simple MFC app using the Visual Studio 2017 project wizard, selecting MDI and Tabbed Documents and Doc/View support. Running the app, I can create new documents, and they show as tabs, all exactly as wanted. I can drag the tabs and dock the document/view windows against the sides of the MDI client area, also exactly as wanted. What I also need is to be able to *programatically* change the docking, from against the sides back to a tab, or vice versa. This seems like the simplest operation, but I've scoured the web looking for hints on how to do it, found nothing useful. Please help, tearing hair out!   :)

Comment: You have all the MFC source code in front of you. When you dock a window manually, it happens during a mouse-button-release event. So, search for all `OnMouseButtonUp` handlers. See how the ones in the docking framework dock the document windows.

Comment: @j6t This is not that simple. Correct me if I am wrong (it happens), finding OnMouseButtonUp handlers will not resolve this issue. This requires a deep understanding of how MDI application and later tabbed window application works. See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

MS documentation from the beginning of the MFC was incomplete.
To understand MFC well, the best documentation is understanding how Windows work and how MFC manages windows as an MFC object with windows handle attached to it.
This applies to your problem too. You have to understand how the tabbed app works.

Maybe this is something new to you, and if not I will mention it anyway. MDI application has a different windows layout in comparison to the SDI app. In SDI app template creates one child frame window with the view as a child of the man windows frame that is in CMainFrame that manages CChildFrame.

MDI application is different. CMainFrame windows client area is occupied by the special child window created with a windows class name "MDIClient".  This is not an MFC class this is a window class passed to Create function. All CChildFrame objects windows are created as children of this special window.

MDI type of application is not introduced by the MFC. It existed before MFC. Nowadays the MFC code is subclassing this window and attaches the handle of the MDIClient windows to a CMDIClientAreaWnd object. You can find it in the CMDIFrameWndEx class; the base class of the CMainFrame window in a tabbed application.

In the tabbed application, the MDI client window managed tab windows that in turn contain all CChildFrame objects. When a new child frame is created it is added to the tab control window single tab group. The window title is drawn in a tab label. When you start dragging and "dock" a window, the new tab group is created and the child frame is added to this group.

I have never done it before and it took me some time to write a code and reduce it according to my MEMC paradigm. The code I have written is just a sample showing how to handle docking. You will have to figure out how to handle different scenarios. The sample shows how to dock when the source and destination tab groups are the same, and that requires the creation of the new tab group and adding the source tab to the new group. When you are trying to dock in a different group you do not have to create the new one, just add to the existing one.
Play with rectangles to determine if a tab is docked on the right or left, on the top or bottom. Some code is reused from an MFC source.
Experiment with different scenarios by dragging and dropping tabs (child windows) to determine the logic used by the framework and mimic it.
The code is written in the menu handler, but you can use any place to invoke it.

```
void CMainFrame::OnDockActive()
{
    CMDIChildWndEx* pMDIFrameWndEx = static_cast<CMDIChildWndEx*>(GetActiveFrame());

    //CMFCTabCtrl& tabDockWnd = pMDIFrameWndEx->GetMDITabs();
    CMFCTabCtrl* pHoveredTabWnd = pMDIFrameWndEx->GetRelatedTabGroup();
    CMFCTabCtrl* pTabWnd = pHoveredTabWnd;

    CRect rectHoveredWnd;
    pHoveredTabWnd->GetWndArea(rectHoveredWnd);
    pHoveredTabWnd->ClientToScreen(rectHoveredWnd);

    if(pTabWnd != pHoveredTabWnd)
    {
        m_wndClientArea.MoveWindowToTabGroup(pTabWnd, pHoveredTabWnd);
    }
    else if(pTabWnd->GetTabsNum() > 1)
    {
        // if horizontal wanted 
        //rectHoveredWnd.top = rectHoveredWnd.bottom - rectHoveredWnd.Height() / 2;
        //CMFCTabCtrl* pNewTabWnd = CreateNewTabGroup(pHoveredTabWnd, rectHoveredWnd, FALSE);

        // for vertical
        rectHoveredWnd.left = rectHoveredWnd.right - rectHoveredWnd.Width() / 2;

        const CObList& m_lstTabbedGroups = GetMDITabGroups();

        POSITION pos = m_lstTabbedGroups.Find(pHoveredTabWnd);

        if(pos == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        MDITabNewGroup(); // will create new group and add child frame to this group
    }
}
```

Comment: @j6t: thanks for that hint; I spent many happy days looking through the source, and found that a lot of private methods were used, but after a lot of experimenting, I found ways of doing it with the public methods. `CMFCTabCtrl::MoveWindowToTabGroup` does a lot of the work, `CWndClientArea::GetMDITabGroups` is useful for iterating over tab groups, and `CWndClientArea::MDITabNewGroup` creates a new tab group. That last one uses a fixed size, half of the available space, but you can adjust it with the `AFX_WM_ON_DRAGCOMPLETE` message.

Comment: At JohnCz (forum keeps deleting my 'at' symbols!) - many thanks for taking the trouble to explain; wish I had waited to see your post!  Your sample code looks something like the way `CMDIClientAreaWnd::OnDragComplete` does it.  Anyway, I have enough now to be able to do what I wanted, which includes switching between 'tabbed view' (all tabs moved to single group) and 'tiled view' (each tab in a group of its own, with equal size for all)

Comment: You are welcome, glad to be of help.